# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'status' of undefined at HTMLInputElement.updateData JSON Javasscript

Tags: javascript, json

I have this code which seems to work perfectly fine till I add the last line. To the best of my knowledge the last line too has no mistake but I keep getting the error

```
firstProjectDifferent_style.html?_ijt=gs7id9qc5jeql1hvnl2cgn56i4:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'status' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.updateData
```

Below is the entire code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JSON Excercise</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Learn JSON</h1>
    <div id="output">
        <ul id="taskList">

        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = '[{"info":"Cut Grass","status":false},{"info":"Clean Room","status":true},' +
            '{"info":"Go to Gyn","status":true},{"info":"Make Dinner Late","status":false}]';

        var dataJSON = JSON.parse(data);
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        var taskList = document.querySelector("#taskList");
        for (var key in dataJSON){
            var status = dataJSON[key].status?"checked":"";
            var html = "<li>"+ dataJSON[key].info + "<input type='checkbox' value='" + dataJSON[key].info + "'" + status +"></li>";
            taskList.innerHTML += html
        }
        addEvent();

        function addEvent() {
            var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("#taskList li input[type='checkbox']");
            for (var index in checkBoxes){
                checkBoxes[index].onchange = updateData;
            }
        }

        function updateData() {
            var key = event.target.value;
            console.log(key, event.target.checked);
            dataJSON[key].status = event.target.checked; //This line is causing the problem
        }



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I'm reading your code right, the `key` you're referring to on the offending line is actually what you pulled from the JSON as `dataJSON[key].info`. This means it's a string ("cut grass" etc.), not a numerical index which you'd need for dataJSON[key] to be defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue is in this lines:

```
function updateData() {
    var key = event.target.value;
```

Change to (the parameter is required):

```
function updateData(event) {
        var key = event.target.value;
```

Second, you cannot access an array of object like this:

```
dataJSON[key]
```

Another issue is your **taskList**: i canged it to **document.querySelector('#taskList')**

I would suggest to use [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

The working code may be:

```js
var data = '[{"info":"Cut Grass","status":false},{"info":"Clean Room","status":true},' +
        '{"info":"Go to Gyn","status":true},{"info":"Make Dinner Late","status":false}]';

var dataJSON = JSON.parse(data);
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var taskList = document.querySelector("#taskList");
for (var key in dataJSON){
    var status = dataJSON[key].status?"checked":"";
    var html = "<li>"+ dataJSON[key].info + "<input type='checkbox' value='" + dataJSON[key].info + "'" + status +"></li>";
    document.querySelector('#taskList').innerHTML += html;
}

addEvent();

function addEvent() {
    var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("#taskList li input[type='checkbox']");
    for (var index in checkBoxes){
        checkBoxes[index].onchange = updateData;
    }
}

function updateData(event) {
    var key = event.target.value;
    dataJSON.filter(function(a, b) {
        return a.info == key;
    })[0].status = event.target.checked;
    console.log(key, event.target.checked);
}
```

```html
<h1>Learn JSON</h1>
<div id="output">
    <ul id="taskList">

    </ul>
</div>
```